# Update JFrame maximized bounds while keeping it maximized

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe, fullscreen

Is it possible to update the maxized bounds of a JFrame (visibly) after calling setMaximizedBounds() while the JFrame is maximized?

```
// I do not have access to / cannot change the following lines
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
// frame fills the whole screen at this point

// My code:
frame.setMaximizedBounds(newBounds);
```

I currently do the following to update the JFrame location and size:

```
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

but this causes the window to visually get restored and then maximized again, but with the correct maximized bounds.

I tried `frame.doLayout()` and `frame.getContentPane().doLayout()` but the frame does not update to the new bounds.

**EDIT** SSCCE:

Adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7403584/1196618).

As mentioned in the comments the JFrame is actually created and initialized by the NetBeans RCP so I cannot override it (as is proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422995/1196618)) as a workaround for [Java bug 4737788](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4737788) (which I am trying to create a workaround for). The workaround works but I would like to avoid the (hack) restore & maximize to update the frame.

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment;


public class MaximizedBoundsTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Fix Maximized Bounds") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // Workaround for https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4737788
                // to take Windows taskbar into account
                GraphicsConfiguration config = frame.getGraphicsConfiguration();
                Rectangle usableBounds = SunGraphicsEnvironment.getUsableBounds(config.getDevice());
                frame.setMaximizedBounds(usableBounds);
                
                // Hack to update frame size & location (is there a better way to do this?)
                frame.setExtendedState(Frame.NORMAL);
                frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            }
        }));
        frame.setExtendedState(Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `// I do not have access to / cannot change the following lines`  Why not?  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: The application uses the NetBeans platform, which creates and initializes the JFrame.

Comment: The Netbeans platform or Netbeans IDE?

Comment: The NetBeans platform (RCP). I use `JFrame frame = (JFrame) WindowManager.getDefault().getMainWindow()` to get the JFrame later on. Sorry for not making that clear in my question.

Comment: Given this might potentially be a bug in the RCP, I'd recommend trying to do it in 'plain old Java code' (an SSCCE).  If it is a bug in the RCP, you'd probably best take it up with them.  If not, the SSCCE will at least give people something to work with, and a solution you might be able to adapt back into the RCP based app.

Comment: I added an SSCCE to my question.

Comment: Huh.. Good question. I don't know the answer, but I'll keep the thread open (in my browser) to see if any of the gurus drop by.  +1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Oh, didn't see that you aren't able to override the frame creating and already found this solution. In that case I would check/file a bug with Netbeans how to override the creation of a JFrame.

Here is my workaround for that bug. PortingUtils in Jide OSS and I believe doesn't use private API but you could use you own bounds calculation there.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;


public class TestUndecoratedFrame {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void setExtendedState(int state) {
                // undecorated covers task bar - http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4737788
                if (isUndecorated()
                        && (state & MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    super.setMaximizedBounds(com.jidesoft.utils.PortingUtils.getScreenBounds(this, true));
                }
                super.setExtendedState(state);
            }
        };
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(800, 600);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Toggle maximize") {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int state = frame.getExtendedState();
                if((state & JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) == JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH) {
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                }
                else {
                    frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
                }
            }
        }), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems like creating the JFrame is the right way to go. Creating a custom JFrame as the Main Window for a NetBeans RCP app is described in [wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqCustomizeWindowSystem](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqCustomizeWindowSystem#Use_own_JFrame_instance_as_the_main_window). I tried it, but it seems there is a race condition (NetBeans bug?) that cause my very basic JFrame to be used sometimes as the Main Window and sometimes not. When it is used as the Main Window though the workaround works, so your answer is the correct approach.