# JDialog on windows extends past the windows taskbar. Any workarounds?

Tags: java, windows, swing, taskbar, jdialog

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422931/why-jframe-hides-taskbar-when-maximized) discusses a known bug where JFrames extend into the windows taskbar.  [An answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422995/411282) links to the bug report (which has various duplicates) and provides a workaround.  I've discovered that the problem also holds for JDialogs.  The JFrame workaround does not apply.  Is there a similar workaround to make JDialogs behave themselves on windows?

Example code:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Demo extends JDialog {
    public Demo() {
        setSize(250,12500);
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Demo();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
It looks like this will not be fixed in the JDK.  [This bug report](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=6798063) closes with the comment that "If a developer wants to keep their windows entirely visible on the screen, they should consider checking the screen insets themselves *[like the solution below]*, and re-layout their component in a different way, or re-size the window manually after calling pack(), or use a screen-insets-aware layout manager *[unlike more common ones like BorderLayout and GridBagLayout]*."

Comment: setMaximumSize( new Dimension( x, y ));?

Comment: I'm hoping for a solution that's resolution-independent like the one in the linked JFrame question.

Comment: Why do you set the size so high? Could you give us some context of what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: I'm just revealing the JDK bug as simply as possible by making y very large.  The actual interface is a scrollpane with many rows and an OK button beneath it.  The OK button is hidden by the taskbar when it is run on Windows.

Comment: *" Is there a similar workaround to make JDialogs behave themselves on windows?"*  Make them 10(?)% smaller than available screen-size?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will basically make sure that the dialog "fits" into the specified screen by moving it to be within the bounds of the specified device and shrinking it so that it's left and bottom edges are within the bounds of the specified device.

This looks at the devices bounds and insets to calculate the "safe" area that the dialog can reside.

```
public class TestScreenSize {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestScreenSize();
    }

    public TestScreenSize() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
                } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
                } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                Test test = new Test();
                test.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                test.setVisible(true);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
    }

    public class Test extends JDialog {

        public Test() {
            setModal(true);
            setLocation(0, 0);
            setSize(2000, 2000);
        }

        @Override
        public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            Rectangle bounds = getSafeScreenBounds(new Point(x, y));
            if (x < bounds.x) {
                x = bounds.x;
            }
            if (y < bounds.y) {
                y = bounds.y;
            }
            if (width > bounds.width) {
                width = (bounds.x + bounds.width) - x;
            }
            if (height > bounds.height) {
                height = (bounds.y + bounds.height) - y;
            }
            super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        }

    }

    public static Rectangle getSafeScreenBounds(Point pos) {

        Rectangle bounds = getScreenBoundsAt(pos);
        Insets insets = getScreenInsetsAt(pos);

        bounds.x += insets.left;
        bounds.y += insets.top;
        bounds.width -= (insets.left + insets.right);
        bounds.height -= (insets.top + insets.bottom);

        return bounds;

    }

    public static Insets getScreenInsetsAt(Point pos) {
        GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDeviceAt(pos);
        Insets insets = null;
        if (gd != null) {
            insets = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenInsets(gd.getDefaultConfiguration());
        }
        return insets;
    }

    public static Rectangle getScreenBoundsAt(Point pos) {
        GraphicsDevice gd = getGraphicsDeviceAt(pos);
        Rectangle bounds = null;
        if (gd != null) {
            bounds = gd.getDefaultConfiguration().getBounds();
        }
        return bounds;
    }

    public static GraphicsDevice getGraphicsDeviceAt(Point pos) {

        GraphicsDevice device = null;

        GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        GraphicsDevice lstGDs[] = ge.getScreenDevices();

        ArrayList<GraphicsDevice> lstDevices = new ArrayList<GraphicsDevice>(lstGDs.length);

        for (GraphicsDevice gd : lstGDs) {

            GraphicsConfiguration gc = gd.getDefaultConfiguration();
            Rectangle screenBounds = gc.getBounds();

            if (screenBounds.contains(pos)) {

                lstDevices.add(gd);

            }

        }

        if (lstDevices.size() > 0) {
            device = lstDevices.get(0);
        } else {
            device = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice();
        }

        return device;

    }
}
```

Comment: frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() | JFrame.ICONIFIED);
            frame.setExtendedState(frame.getExtendedState() & (~JFrame.ICONIFIED));

Comment: @mKorbel JDialog doesn't have extended set :(

Comment: right, my bad ......... automatic complier opened one of drawer in cabinet and as am realased to flush here a.m. code lines...

Comment: Causes I use a template. Causes I have a personal dislike for metal

Answer (score 1):

Ok, no magic below, but as simple as max(a,b):

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class Demo extends JDialog {
   public Demo() {
      super((Frame)null, "Demo" );
      setDefaultCloseOperation( DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE );

      Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
      int width  = Math.min(    250, screenSize.width );
      int height = Math.min( 12_500, screenSize.height );
      pack();
      setSize( width, height );
      setVisible( true );
   }
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      new Demo();
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't neglect to `pack()` before `setSize()`.

Comment: `getScreenSize` won't take into consideration the task bar, it is the raw the resolution of the screen.