# Can I maximize a JFrame without hiding the taskbar?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I tried to make a JFrame window, that is maximized automatically within the program  and tried:

`this.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

And the window did maximize, but the taskbar was hidden. Is there any way to maximize, without hiding it?

Comment: Possible workaround to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6422995/243373)

Comment: I've never seen this problem. Post your [mre] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: What is the "*taskbar*" - the Windows one? And are you sure about using `setState()` - from its [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Frame.html#setState(int)): "*If the state passed to this method is neither Frame.NORMAL nor Frame.ICONIFIED the method performs no actions at all.*" ?

Comment: @user85421 You're right! I used `setExtendedState()`. I found a way to maximize it on start, now I cannot change it to maximized state back when it got dragged by the user. And I'm using **Windows 11**!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.